# How to Empty Gmail Trash with C#

Tags: c#, .net, imap, gmail-imap, interimap

I tried to access my Gmail mailbox with [InterImap](http://interimap.codeplex.com/) Library. It shows my messages there, but unable to delete messages. I also found a method "EmptyFolder()" but doesn't work.

All that worked for me is MoveMessageToFolder() but it's not that I need.

Please help me empty my Trash with C# using the same or any other library. I need the code sample that does that.

Here's the code what I managed to write.

```
var config = new InterIMAP.IMAPConfig("imap.gmail.com", "<my gmail username>", "<my gmail password", true, true, "");
var client = new InterIMAP.Synchronous.IMAPClient(config, new InterIMAP.IMAPLogger(config, new object[] { }), 1);
var trash = client.Folders["[Gmail]"].SubFolders["Trash"];
trash.EmptyFolder();
client.Logoff();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Q: So it sounds like a) you're not able to "delete" a message with InterIMap, and b) you're also not able to "clear trash" with InterIMap, correct?  Please look at this post and see if it helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491939/cant-mark-email-read-with-interimap-folder-is-read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a message from your Inbox or one of your custom folders, it will still appear in [Gmail]/All Mail.

Here’s why: in most cases, deleting a message simply removes that folder’s label from the message, including the label identifying the message as being in your Inbox.

[Gmail]/All Mail shows all of your messages, whether or not they have labels attached to them.

If you want to permanently delete a message from all folders:

1. Move it to the [Gmail]/Trash folder.
2. Delete it from the [Gmail]/Trash folder.

You can find more details here:
http://www.limilabs.com/blog/delete-email-permanently-in-gmail

Comment: I had already tried this with InterIMAP that I was using, but it only worked with the Mail.dll downloaded from your link. Anyways, thanks for the solution, It's now working for me.. whatever the goal was.

Answer (score 2):

I dislike deleting the trash folder in Gmail manually. It's full of spam everyday.
So I copied c# code to do the job for me. I downloaded and used mail.dll from Limilabs, the evaluation version. Create a Gmail password for apps. 
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using Limilabs.Client.IMAP;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace delete_gmail_trash
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Imap imap = new Imap())
            {
                imap.ConnectSSL("imap.gmail.com");
                imap.UseBestLogin("username@gmail.com", "password for Gmail apps");
                // Recognize Trash folder
                List<FolderInfo> folders = imap.GetFolders();

                CommonFolders common = new CommonFolders(folders);

                FolderInfo trash = common.Trash;
                // Find all emails we want to delete
                imap.Select(trash);
                List<long> uidList = imap.Search(Flag.All);
                foreach (long uid in uidList)
                {
                    imap.DeleteMessageByUID(uid);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} deleted", uid);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                imap.Close();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```